# Woocommerce show each categories with their products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can go to 'WooCommerce -> Settings' link from side bar admin menu & select 'Catalog' tab & then tick 2 check boxes "Show subcategories on the shop page"
But this shows a list of categories, then all products.
What i want is on shop page, At first category title, then its products under it, then next category and its products.

In short, i want to list all products category wise.

Answer (score 29):

You could create a new shop page and use the woocommerce shortcodes in combination with headers to create a list of products organized by category. For example, in the HTML editor you could do something like this:

```
<h2>Category Name</h2>
[product_category category="category-name" per_page="12" columns="4" orderby="date" order="desc"]
```

Comment: tried it and it works fine, without needing heavy dev skills. I suggest this answer be accepted as it gives a proper solution to the given problem.

Comment: Worked great for me to.

Comment: It worked for me also. I was trying to do this by modifying the code but never thought its this much easy.

Comment: can you add filters , if you do it like this?